# Why is the object in the selected row not getting deleted from the array selectedIndexes

Tags: ios, objective-c

Any idea why the object in the selected row of the table view not getting deleted from the array (selected indexes)

Below is my code to delete (in the else section)

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *selectedIndexes;

//...

_files = @[@"filea", @"fileb", @"filec"];

//...

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ([selectedCell accessoryType] == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) 
    {
        NSString *filename = [_files objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [selectedCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
        [selectedIndexes addObject:filename];
    }
    else    
    {
        [selectedCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
         NSString *objecttoDelete =   [selectedIndexes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [selectedIndexes removeObject:objecttoDelete];
    }

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You've got a logical problem here:

---

Let's say that I click row number three in your table; well then your array will look like this:

```
[0 => "Row 3 content"]
```

Then I click row 1:

```
[0 => "Row 3 content"
 1 => "Row 1 content"]
```

So to be clear, row 3 (index 2 in the table) is in index 0.

---

Now let's say that I go to remove row 3. I click it:

```
//indexPath.row == 2, so
objectToRemove = [selectedIndexes objectAtIndex:2] //<--Index 2!!!
```

Uh oh :O ! I'm trying to remove the object at index 2! When you try to remove the object, you are not taking into account the order that they are being added to the array!

---

## Now for the fix

Since the objects are not changing, you can simply get the object to remove in the same way that you got it to add it...make sense?

Well, anyways, get the object the same way:

```
NSString *filename = [_files objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

This will get the proper string. Then you can remove it by searching with a for-loop (there may be a cleaner way to do this with references, but here you go):

```
for(int i = 0; i < [selectedIndexes count]; i++)
{
    if([[selectedIndexes objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:filename])
    {
        [selectedIndexes removeObjectAtIndex:i];
        break;
    }
}
```

Hope this makes sense. If you have any questions, comment.

Comment: thankyou David for clearing the real problem, that really helped.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the things you are trying to delete aren't strings? Perhaps try

```
id *objectToDelete =  [selectedIndexes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[selectedIndexes removeObject:objecttoDelete];
```

instead. Or have you thought about skipping that and just using `removeAtObjectAtIndex:`?

```
[selectedIndexes removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: i have tried you second suggestion and its not working

Comment: basically what i want to do is add the text of the clicked cell to a array,  and delete it from the array again when i click it the second time

Comment: looking more closely at it, it looks like it should be getting deleted. Are you sure that it is still in the array? or just in the tableView..  Are you doing an NSLog or breakpoint or something like that to check the array?

Comment: You do have enough rep to comment.

Comment: oks got it solved . had to change  NSString *objecttoDelete =   [selectedIndexes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; to  NSString *objecttoDelete =   [_files objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; thanks for the help